# Can someone help me with timer and sound events?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

so I'm trying to create a title screen that displays and image and disapears after 5 seconds, and than as soon as the program is started a song is played. This song will play out through the entirety of the game.

```
    public function TitleScreen(){//adds a Title Screen
    var tsBackground:tsBack= new tsBack();
    tsBackground.x= -22
    tsBackground.width=650
    tsBackground.height=450
    addChild(tsBackground);

    var mainTheme:tsTheme = new tsTheme(); 
    mainTheme.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler); 
    function completeHandler(event:TimerEvent){
    mainTheme.play();
    }

    var counter = 0;
    var myTimer:Timer = new Timer(5000);
    myTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, TimerFunction)
    function TimerFunction(event:TimerEvent){
        counter++
        removeChild(tsBackground);
        AddStuff();
    }
    myTimer.start();

    /*if (myTimer >= 5000) {
        myTimer.stop();
     }*/

}//end of TitleScreen
```

I commented out the if statement that determines if it stops because I get this error:

```
1176: Comparison between a value with static type flash.utils:Timer and a possibly unrelated type int.
```

The second problem I have is that the song isn't playing when mainTheme.play(); is invoked, and I know I did the linkage properly.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Does anyone have any idea? The last commend didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is telling you are trying to compare your `myTimer` object (which is of type `Timer`) to an integer (5000). It's like trying to ask "Which is greater: the number 3 or this lamp?". I think you meant to compare your `counter` variable, but even that is not going to work how you want it to.

Your `TimerFunction` is the function that runs when your timer hits zero. So there is no need to do that comparison. You already know when the 5 seconds is up because that function will run. So you can just stop the timer there. You probably also want to remove the event listener there:

```
function TimerFunction(event:TimerEvent){
    removeChild(tsBackground);
    AddStuff();
    myTimer.stop();
    myTimer.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, TimerFunction);
    mainTheme.play();
}
```